# SQL - single user database vs offline database

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to restore database, but it gives me error of exclusive rights.

now i can set my database to single user or set offline to restore it.

so, my question is what is difference between both of these?

which is better way to get around these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Database Single-user mode:-**
Single-user mode specifies that only one user at a time can access the database and is generally used for maintenance actions

Limitations and Restrictions:-
If other users are connected to the database at the time that you set the database to single-user mode, their connections to the database will be closed without warning.
The database remains in single-user mode even if the user that set the option logs off. At that point, a different user, but only one, can connect to the database.

**Database Offline Mode:-**
Database is unavailable. A database becomes offline by explicit user action and remains offline until additional user action is taken

Comment: so, which one is best?

Comment: to restore a db first try to kill the connections and then restore it. If that is not possible then go for single user mode. Are you using .bak file  or another db to restore it?

Comment: most of cases i generate scripts, but if database is more then i prefer .bak file.

Answer (score 2):

Offline means that nobody can access the database.  Single user means that only one person can, presumably you.  I dont think it matters which way you go to be honest.

A better way to get around these two options?  It would take a bit of extra work to allow only reads while restoring.  It gets really complicated if you want the database to allow writes while you do a restore operation.

If there are no open connections to the database when you do the restore you can leave it online but it is probably not a good practice depending on your specific situation.